# Select2 bootstrap element not sizing up as expected

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

I'm trying to set the layout of my page with [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) `input-group` and `form-control`, one of which wraps a [Select2](https://select2.org) element.

Here is a part of my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-3">
    <div id='status-input-group' class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <label id="label" class="input-group-text" for="status">Status</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select id="status" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="label"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='invoice-input-group' class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <label id="label" class="input-group-text" for="invoice-id">Invoice</label>
        </div>
        <input id="invoice-id" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="label" disabled />
    </div>
...
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I expected the `select2` element's right edge to be aligned with the input below.

I tried to set `style="width: 100%;"` for the `div` containing the `select2`. But then the width of the `select2` became the same as the full width of the element below and went to another row.

[image]

How do I make the `select2` element fill all free space of the column but not more?

I tried to set `width` manually to something like `77%`, but it holds only on specific window width so isn't a solution at all.

Comment: Why do you have a div wrapper around the select element? That's probably breaking Bootstrap's styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update to work with JQuery [select2](https://select2.org)

Select2 replaces the native `select` element with an element that it generates and manages. When it generates its element, it looks at the parent's size to size itself, if you size the parent element, the select2 will have the size you expect.

[image]

Using `width` won't give you the expected results because you are inside the `input-group` which is a `flex` element, you can make the container grow using the [`flex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Since your example uses Bootstrap4, and there is a [bootstrap4 theme](https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme) for it, you can use it directly, either through the CDN, or installing, to make the select2 style match the rest of your inputs.

```js
$('#status').select2({
  theme: 'bootstrap4'
});

$('#status-s').select2({
  // ...
});

$('#status-w').select2({
  // ...
});
```

```css
#s2-container-good {
  flex: 1;
}

#s2-container-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme@1.3.4/dist/select2-bootstrap4.min.css" integrity="sha256-J6L5BfjnEuIwj6+OSc2OBxc8+BEGW3ZTz7wDHepaayI=" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-3">
  <div class="legend">Using flex: 1</div>
  <div id='status-input-group' class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <label id="label" class="input-group-text" for="status">Status</label>
    </div>
    <div id="s2-container-good">
      <select id="status" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="label">
        <option>Done</option>
        <option>Waiting</option>
        <option>Undefined</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='invoice-input-group' class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <label id="label" class="input-group-text" for="invoice-id">Invoice</label>
    </div>
    <input id="invoice-id" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="label" disabled />
  </div>
  <!-- This select will not use the full width -->
  <div class="legend">No CSS</div>
  <div id='status-input-group' class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <label id="label" class="input-group-text" for="status">Status</label>
    </div>
    <div id="s2-container-no-css">
      <select id="status-s" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="label">
        <option>Done</option>
        <option>Waiting</option>
        <option>Undefined</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- This select will jump to the next line -->
  <div class="legend">Width: 100%</div>
  <div id='status-input-group' class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <label id="label" class="input-group-text" for="status">Status</label>
    </div>
    <div id="s2-container-width">
      <select id="status-w" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="label">
        <option>Done</option>
        <option>Waiting</option>
        <option>Undefined</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Original answer below

Remove the `div` wrapping the select and it will work.

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-3">
  <div id='status-input-group' class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <label id="label" class="input-group-text" for="status">Status</label>
    </div>
    <select id="status" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="label">
      <option>Mustard</option>
      <option>Ketchup</option>
      <option>Relish</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id='invoice-input-group' class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <label id="label" class="input-group-text" for="invoice-id">Invoice</label>
    </div>
    <input id="invoice-id" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="label" disabled />
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't. That was actually an original layout (without div). I believe it has something to do with Select2

Comment: Did you try the snippet? @Ralfeus It works for me in Firefox and Chromium

Comment: It does work. However if I add ```$('#status').select2({theme: 'bootstrap', data: ...});``` then I get the picture as on the screenshot

Comment: that's it! Thanks a lot! Just one question - how to handle elements height difference?

Comment: You can use this [select2-bootstrap4 theme](https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme). You could also style it manually, but using the theme, besides being easier, will probably end up working better on the long run. I updated the answer to use it on the 'correct' example.